# Setup AWS RDS for EC2 instance with WHM

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I have an AWS EC2 instance and we have installed WHM, now we want a replica of My DB via RDS (daily automated backup copy of my db is replicated via rds), I have tried to search the process but nothing found, can anyone help pls. we are not very familier with AWS but due to client requirement, we have set up the AWS. our stack is LAMP.

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you want a copy of a local database in RDS, do you want a copy of an RDS database on your server, do you want a backup file, etc.

Comment: i want my mysql database copy on RDS

Answer (score 0):

**Option One**

The [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) is ideal for this. It's fairly trivial to use.

Note: it does't copy indexes, auto-increment information, or a variety of other information, or at least it didn't for me. You might be best off with a manual import then using database migration service to keep it up to date.

From the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/faqs/)

**Q.** In addition to one-time data migration, can I use AWS Database Migration Service for continuous data replication?

**A.** Yes, you can use AWS Database Migration Service for both one-time data migration into RDS and EC2-based databases as well as for continuous data replication. AWS Database Migration Service will capture changes on the source database and apply them in a transactionally-consistent way to the target. Continuous replication can be done from your data center to the databases in AWS or in the reverse, replicating to a database in your datacenter from a database in AWS. Ongoing continuous replication can also be done between homogenous or heterogeneous databases. For ongoing replication it would be preferable to use Multi-AZ for high-availability.

**Option Two**

Your other option is the [AWS data pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/). It's also capable of this.

You'll want to understand and consider both options. I think both will do the job fine, maybe look at ease of use and price.